# xades4j: How to sign with SubjectKeyIdentifier (tag <ds:X509SKI>)

Tags: xades4j

In my project I use xades4j Java library to make digital signature on xml data.

I can't find how to make signature with included SubjectKeyIdentifier (exist in used certificate as extension with ObjectId: 2.5.29.14) as tag ?

I suggest that is configured by setting XadesSigningProfile:

```
XadesSigningProfile p = new XadesBesSigningProfile(kp)
    .withBasicSignatureOptions(
        new BasicSignatureOptions()
            .includeIssuerSerial(true)
            .includePublicKey(true)
            .includeSigningCertificate(SigningCertificateMode.SIGNING_CERTIFICATE)
            .includeSubjectName(true)
            .signKeyInfo(true)
        )//??????
    .withAlgorithmsProviderEx(new MyAlgorithmProvider());
```

Best regards,
Josip

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no way to include that element. Feel free to submit a PR or open an issue on the project's site.